# Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden]

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: age description here]

[image]

I tried to execute API from postman, but I am getting 403 forbidden error, but i verified with all request headers, I have doubt that there will be some problem with `serviceImplementation` class I need assistance.

I tried to Google errors but am not able to fix it, kindly someone go through my code, if there any problem with logic guide me.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't post images of your code but copy&paste the code itself.